# xDebug [Errno 24] Too many open files when connecting to DBGp Proxy

Tags: xdebug

I'm having issues running an xDebug session when I've connected to the DBGp proxy successfully.  I'm using both local and remote SSH tunnels for port 9000 (xdebug), and 9001 for a (xdebug DBGp client).

] The code is being debugged remotely, the xDebug server is running on an Amazon EC2 instance

] I am using Zend Studio for my local debugging client on my Macbook

] I am running a remote SSH tunnel for port 9000 "ssh ec2-user@X.X.X.X -R 9000/127.0.0.1/9000"

As of here, I'm able to successfully use xDebug, but then I run into issues running the proxy

---

But then I start running into issues running the proy:

] I then run the dbgp proxy on the remote server

```
./pydbgpproxy 
INFO: dbgp.proxy: starting proxy listeners.  appid: 20906
INFO: dbgp.proxy:     dbgp listener on 127.0.0.1:9000
INFO: dbgp.proxy:     IDE listener on  127.0.0.1:9001
```

] I then setup a local SSH tunnel for port 9001 - "ssh ec2-user@X.X.X.X -L 9001/127.0.0.1/9001"

] From Zend Studio I'm able to connect successfully to the DBGp server, where "SessionName" is the name of my session

```
INFO: dbgp.proxy: Server:onConnect ('127.0.0.1', 51828) [proxyinit -p 9000 -k SessionName -m 0]
```

] When I trigger a remote xdebug debugging sessions using my session name, it fails like so.

```
INFO: dbgp.proxy: connection from 127.0.0.1:39172 [<__main__.sessionProxy instance at 0x122e0e0>]
INFO: dbgp.proxy: connection from 127.0.0.1:39173 [<__main__.sessionProxy instance at 0x7f87980210e0>]
INFO: dbgp.proxy: connection from 127.0.0.1:39174 [<__main__.sessionProxy instance at 0x7f87980243b0>]
INFO: dbgp.proxy: connection from 127.0.0.1:39175 [<__main__.sessionProxy instance at 0x7f879814c878>]
INFO: dbgp.proxy: connection from 127.0.0.1:39176 [<__main__.sessionProxy instance at 0x7f87800a2368>]
INFO: dbgp.proxy: connection from 127.0.0.1:39177 [<__main__.sessionProxy instance at 0x123cb48>]
INFO: dbgp.proxy: connection from 127.0.0.1:39178 [<__main__.sessionProxy instance at 0x12387e8>]
INFO: dbgp.proxy: connection from 127.0.0.1:39179 [<__main__.sessionProxy instance at 0x122ec68>]
INFO: dbgp.proxy: connection from 127.0.0.1:39180 [<__main__.sessionProxy instance at 0x124fb48>]
INFO: dbgp.proxy: connection from 127.0.0.1:39181 [<__main__.sessionProxy instance at 0x7f8798047dd0>]
INFO: dbgp.proxy: connection from 127.0.0.1:39182 [<__main__.sessionProxy instance at 0x1244d88>]

ERROR: dbgp.proxy: Unable to connect to the server listener 127.0.0.1:9000 [<__main__.sessionProxy instance at 0x7f8790025878>]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./pydbgpproxy", line 222, in startServer

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 184, in __init__

error: [Errno 24] Too many open files

WARNING: dbgp.proxy: Unable to connect to server with key [SessionName], stopping request [<__main__.sessionProxy instance at 0x7f8790025878>]

WARNING: dbgp.proxy: Exception in _cmdloop [[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer]

INFO: dbgp.proxy: session stopped
```

---

It actually shows those lines like "INFO: dbgp.proxy: connection from 127.0.0.1:39179 [<**main**.sessionProxy instance at 0x122ec68>]" almost 50x more than what I copied and pasted here for brevity.

It seems like I got it to work but it's erring out.  I'm currently using the pydbgpproxy phyton script, version 7 from:  http://code.activestate.com/komodo/remotedebugging/.  I tried the version 8 script but it just errors. I also tried the pydbgpprox, version 6, but it still has the same exact issue.

IN SUMMARY: xDebug is running on the server, I can connect to it normally without proxy.  With the proxy I can connect to it successfully to, but then running a script it encounters this werid error.

Does anyone know what this issue might be caused from?

Comment: I found another solution, than relying on the pydbgpproxy script which seems to have a lot of issues.  When the PHP files are executed on the remote server for debugging, I automatically set a unique xdebug.remote_port in the php_ini settings per developer.  I do this by setting up a unique xdebug.remote_port in our virtualhost files and by setting it when I run the php from the command line.

Comment: So another way to allow mutiple developers working gat the same time on the box, when you need to SSH tunnel into the server, is just assigning each developer a unique port and making sure when their PHP scripts run, at run-time before the php script starts the xdebug.remote_port is set to their unique port number.  It does the same thing as the proxy.  It's probably not ideal as the pydbgpproxy proxy, but this is the only way I could get this to work. I spent 2 days on this.

Comment: the same problem, can anyone answer this question ?